# rails 7 migrating rails react app from webpacker to esbuild

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I have the following error trying to import app/javascript/channels from app/javascript/channels/index.js I know that require is a webpack command so if I'm not using webpack I'm gonna use import instead but I don't know the syntax
reference error: required is not defined var channels = require.context(".", true, /_channel.js$/);